# Python: wrapper for C++ requires access to .dll files

Tags: python, c++, windows, dll, swig

I made a Python wrapper for an SDK written in C++ using SWIG and built using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7.

It's been a success, with the *module.py* and *_module.pyd* being generated. However, this wrapper heavily depends on a couple .dll files located in the SDK folder outside PythonXY folder.

After I moved the *module.py* and *module.pyd* into *PythonXY/Lib/site-packages/*, and tried running **import module**, the following error occurs:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Then, I tried to change the Python working directory to the directory where the .dll files exist, using **os.chdir()** method from Python module *os*. This time, running **import module** output no error. I continued to access the wrapped C++ classes and functions and they worked just fine.

My questions are:

- How can I "link" the path containing the .dll files so whenever I want to use **module**, I don't have to change the working directory?
- Is there any way to append additional working directory aside from Python default working directory from within the Python source file? (i.e. not from PATH configuration on Windows)
- Is there any way I can link the wrapper with those .dll files dynamically? Meaning that let say the files are copied to another machine and the .dll files are stored in different absolute path directory, the **import module** would still work?

The point is I want to make this wrapper as portable as possible, across multiple Windows machine.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried putting it somewhere where Windows would look for DLLs?

Comment: How can I check which directories Windows would look for the DLLs?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to let *module.py* find *_module.pyd*.

Basically, create a new file called *module.pth* and save it in the same directory as *module.py*. In this case, the directory is PythonXY/Lib/site-packages/.

Let say you place your *_module.pyd* inside a directory called *_modulelib* (PythonXY/Lib/site-packages/_modulelib/), then the content of *module.pth* should be like this:

```
_modulelib
```